# How to get 'GetPropertyValue' result in JSON format in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, json

I have tried adding outputFormat = application/json but not working :( my URL looks like this

```
http://domain/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.3.0&request=GetPropertyValue&typeNames=forest:division&valueReference=name&outputFormat=application/json
```

I also tried WFS version 2.0.0

```
http://domain/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetPropertyValue&typeNames=forest:division&valueReference=name&format=application/json
```

I'm getting results as follows. :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My local GeoServer (2.18.1) only supports one output format, so there is no point in trying to get it as JSON:

```
<ows:Operation name="GetPropertyValue">
  <ows:DCP>                                                                               
    <ows:HTTP>                                                                            
      <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.18.1/wfs"/>                  
      <ows:Post xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.18.1/wfs"/>                 
    </ows:HTTP>                                                                           
  </ows:DCP>                                                                              
  <ows:Parameter name="resolve">                                                          
    <ows:AllowedValues>                                                                   
      <ows:Value>none</ows:Value>                                                         
      <ows:Value>local</ows:Value>                                                        
    </ows:AllowedValues>                                                                  
  </ows:Parameter>                                                                        
  <ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">                                                     
    <ows:AllowedValues>                                                                   
      <ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>                             
    </ows:AllowedValues>                                                                  
  </ows:Parameter>                                                                        
</ows:Operation>
```

Comment: Correct, it would be possible to add new output formats, but one has to write code to do so.